# Find date based on week + dayofweek mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, dayofweek

Suppose I know the day of the `DAYOFWEEK()`, and I know the `WEEK()` and `YEAR()` numbers. Is it possible to format a date out of these values in *mysql* ?

Comment: If you have (or are willing to create) a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql) this would be a very easy task indeed.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but suppose that's not possible. Can it be done in the form of a query?

Comment: Why would you want to use an RDBMS for this?

Comment: I am trying to create a pointer to another row by selecting the row that matches the current row's DAYOFWEEK(), WEEK() and YEAR()-1. Basically I am trying to point to the same day of last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014-20-2','%Y-%U-%w')-INTERVAL 1 DAY n;
+------------+
| n          |
+------------+
| 2014-05-19 |
+------------+
```

The INTERVAL bit is to account for the fact that %w interprets days of the week as 0 (Sunday) to 6, whereas DAYOFWEEK goes from 1(Sunday) to 7 - go figure!!!

It's possible that %U also works slightly differently from WEEK(); the above appears to give the right answer so I haven't looked into it further.

Comment: This looks very usefull. It's not exactly what I need, but that's due to the nature of how I phrased my question. I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with sql so I'll just write logic i would use for solving that problem.

We know what current year it is (YEAR()). We could use fact that 1.1.1900. was monday to calculate what day of week was at 1.1. of current year. Then we could calculate which dates are in the current week(WEEK()). Again using fact that 1.1.1900. was monday, we could calculate which day of week would be every one of them and compare that with current day of week (DAYOFWEEK()).

Again, I'm not good with sql so it is possible that this is highly inefficient solution. But I hope this at least gives you some ideas and help you find your solution. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1400463204), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS date,
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1400463204), CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1400463204)-INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'-','%U-%w')), '%Y-%U-%w %H:%i:s') AS samedaylastyear,
DAYOFWEEK(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1400463204), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) AS check1,
DAYOFWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1400463204), CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1400463204)-INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'-','%U-%w')), '%Y-%U-%w %H:%i:s')) AS check2
```